# populate handlebars.js template with an array of strings from js

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have no clue if this is even possible, but I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to do it. I have an array of string values in my .js file which include html tags. An array similar to this:

```
var values = [
    <h1>Introduction</h1>,
    <h3>Words</h3>,
    <p>More words</p>
]
```

I am attempting to have them inserted into a handlebars template, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. I have tried using a variation of a {{ #each _ }} method for node.js to no avail. Please let me know how to do this, or if it's even possible.

---

Here's my current code. I am trying to just get the array of data to display when it's hard-coded in the html. I am getting no errors, but the code does not display.
    
    
    eSOMS Tutorial

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="c://node.js/server.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script id="content-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each data}}
          {{this}}
    {{/each}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var data = [
            '<h1>Introduction</h1>',
            '<h3>The Enterprise Shift Operations Management System</h3>',
            '<p>The Enterprise Shift Operations...</p>',
            '<p>The purpose of this tutorial is to...</p>'
        ];

      if(!Handlebars.templates){ Handlebars.templates = {}; }

      Handlebars.templates.full = Handlebars.compile($("#content-template").html());  
      $('#output').html(Handlebars.templates.full({data: data}));
    });
  </script>

  <div id='output'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

There's much more code but I think I've got everything relevant.

Comment: Surely you can find the answer to this in the [docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#iterators).

Comment: You would think so.

Comment: Alright. Where are you getting stuck? What does your template look like? How do you call it?

Comment: I've updated the posted source code.

Comment: For one thing, generally speaking to render HTML as HTML (i.e. unescaped) you'd typically use three braces not two. Nor is it at all clear why you don't just `.join` the array.

Comment: I understand that, I have been changing things around in the code for awhile and just forgot to change it back. I've tried that as well and it doesn't work. Also, I'm not familiar with the join() function. Is it a Handlebars function? How would I use it?

Comment: I would follow what @JaredSmith wrote. There is no point in using a template if there is no interpolation to do. All you should need is: `$('#output').html(data.join(''));`.